# Replacing autoref command format specification in auctex's font-latex-match-reference-keywords-local

Tags: auctex, font-lock, replace, list

With some help I have redefined the `autoref` command to take an optional argument, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428229/autoref-with-optional-argument-text-in-generated-link

Now I am trying to convince Emacs/auctex to properly syntax highlight the new command. AFAICT setting it through `font-latex-match-reference-keywords` does not work as it is already defined by auctex itself, but actually only once auctex has recognized the LaTeX document loads hyperref.

When I `M-: (setcar (cdr (TeX-assoc-string "autoref" font-latex-match-reference-keywords-local)) "*[{")` in an open LaTeX source file I seem to get what I want. However, I cannot seem to get this working automatically...

I've placed the above line in a defun `jk/tex-mode-hook` and then added that to `TeX-mode-hook`

```
(defun jk/tex-mode-hook ()
    "Set up TeX mode (auctex)"
    (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace nil t)
    (setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t
          reftex-refstyle "\\autoref")
    (setcar (cdr (TeX-assoc-string "autoref" font-latex-match-reference-keywords-local)) "*[{")
)
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'jk/tex-mode-hook)
```

but to no avail...

How do I evaluate the (correct) replacement command late enough to become effective in my LaTeX sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docstring of `font-latex-match-reference-keywords-local` says:

> `font-latex-match-reference-keywords-local` is a variable defined in
>   ‘font-latex.el’.
>
> Documentation:
>   Buffer-local keywords to add to
>   `font-latex-match-reference-keywords`.
>
> This must be a list where each element is a list consisting of a
>   keyword string (not a regular expression) omitting the leading
>   backslash and a format specifier as described in the doc string of
>   `font-latex-user-keyword-classes`.
>
> This is an internal variable which should not be set directly. Use
>   `font-latex-add-keywords` instead.

For this kind of additions, I strongly suggest put your .tex code in an extra package `autoref-withopt.sty` which can look like this:

```latex
\ProvidesPackage{autoref-withopt}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{letltxmacro}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\autoreforig\autoref
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoref}{som}{%
    \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
      \hyperref[#3]%
    }{%
      \autoreforig*{#3}\IfValueT{#2}{#2}%
    }%
  }%
}
\endinput
```

The corresponding AUCTeX style file looks like this:

```lisp
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "autoref-withopt"
 (lambda ()
   ;; Make sure we load hyperref.el
   (TeX-run-style-hooks "hyperref")

   ;; Make \autoref available with opt. argument
   (TeX-add-symbols
    '("autoref"  [ "Text" ] TeX-arg-ref)
    '("autoref*" [ "Text" ] TeX-arg-ref))

   ;; Fontification
   (when (and (fboundp 'font-latex-add-keywords)
              (eq TeX-install-font-lock 'font-latex-setup))
     (font-latex-add-keywords '(("autoref" "*[{"))
                              'reference)))
 LaTeX-dialect)
```

In your init file, add these lines and save the code above in the directory specified in `TeX-style-private` as `autoref-withopt.el`

```lisp
(setq TeX-style-private
      (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/private-styles"))
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

In your .tex file, add `\usepackage{autoref-withopt}` and restart Emacs, open your .tex file again and hit <kbd>C-c RET autoref RET</kbd>.

Comment: Great, thank you Arash!  For completeness, simply putting `(TeX-run-style-hooks "hyperref")` before the `(setcar ...` also works, but kind of assumes that hyperref+the modified autoref is always loaded – which it effectively is for me... But the clean solution by Arash is way more general and much nicer – and what I am using now! ;-)