# fontify autoref and nameref in latex-mode buffers

Tags: latex, auctex, font-lock

When I'm in a `.tex` file, press `M-:` and run

```
(font-latex-add-keywords '(("autoref" "*{") ("Autoref" "{") ("nameref" "*{"))
                         'reference)
```

the buffer fontifies occurrences of `\nameref` and `\autoref` appropriately (and my custom-defined `\Autoref`. However, if I put this same code in my `.emacs` file (say under the `:config` section of `(use-package auctex ...` or in the `latex-mode-hook`), then those macros are no longer fontified as references in `.tex` buffers. How do I fix this?

This is a [related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41204/replacing-autoref-command-format-specification-in-auctexs-font-latex-match-refe), but I am looking for a simpler solution that, ideally, simply incorporates the one-liner above.

Answer (score 1):

Call your setting from the `LaTeX-mode-hook`. It's not very user friendly but `latex-mode-hook` is defined in `tex-mode.el`, which is built-in but not part of AUCTeX, while `LaTeX-mode-hook` comes from `latex.el` which is part of AUCTeX.

So this should work,

```lisp
(defun my-LaTeX-mode-setup ()
  (font-latex-add-keywords '(("autoref" "*{") ("Autoref" "{") ("nameref" "*{"))
                         'reference))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'my-LaTeX-mode-setup)
```

Comment: I have tried what you said, and this does not work for me.

Comment: @bashfuloctopus I just tried with the code above as the sole content of my init file and it worked (on Emacs 27.1).  Are you sure your AUCTeX is up to date and there are not other settings that may interfere? Maybe try for yourself running Emacs with just my code in the init. If it works, there's something else that interferes.